# Java Apache POI NoClassDefFoundError WorkbookFacory

Tags: java, rmi, apache-poi, excel

I am trying to call a method on server-side implemented by Java RMI. This method will open, read and do some data manipulation in the excel spreadsheet.

```
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);
```

This is the code which I get the following exception. `inp` is a InputStream with specified filepath.

> Exception: java.rmi.ServerError: Error occurred in server thread; nested exception is:
>           **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookFacory**

I did also try to call this method locally, which gave no error.

Now, Server and Client are both running on the same machine(localhost).

Comment: On the server side, did you forget to add the JAR file that contains the POI classes to your classpath? `NoClassDefFoundError` (almost) always means that there's something missing from your classpath.

Answer (score 2):

Add the POI classes to your server's classpath. Just because the client and server are running on the same machine doesn't mean that both share a common classpath.